# How to send image to server with Blob type using Axios in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I try to select a picture from the gallery, and I got data like below:

```
{  
   "exif":null,
   "localIdentifier":"9F983DBA-EC35-42B8-8773-B597CF782EDD/L0/001",
   "filename":"IMG_0003.JPG",
   "width":500,
   "modificationDate":null,
   "mime":"image/jpeg",
   "sourceURL":"file:///Users/vichit/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3BBFABAC-2171-49AA-8B2B-8C2764949258/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0003.JPG",
   "height":500,
   "creationDate":"1344451932"
}
```

For this time, I want to send this picture to the server with Blob type using Axios.

I don't know how to convert this picture to a Blob type.

Comment: I did this with [`react-native-fetch-blob`](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob)

Answer (score 6):

It's simple:

```js
async function uploadToServer(sourceUrl) {
    // first get our hands on the local file
    const localFile = await fetch(sourceUrl);

    // then create a blob out of it (only works with RN 0.54 and above)
    const fileBlob = await localFile.blob();

    // then send this blob to filestack
    const serverRes = await fetch('https://www.yourAwesomeServer.com/api/send/file', { // Your POST endpoint
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': fileBlob && fileBlob.type,
        },
        body: fileBlob, // This is your file object
    });

    const serverJsonResponse = await serverRes.json();

    // yay, let's print the result
    console.log(`Server said: ${JSON.stringify(serverJsonResponse)}`);
}
```

And run like `uploadToServer("file:///Users/vichit/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3BBFABAC-2171-49AA-8B2B-8C2764949258/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0003.JPG")`

It took me forever to figure it out, but it makes sense now.

I hope that helps someone!